# XSL: sorting the document in first transform and then transform based on key

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Cannot achieve the desired result when converting the original document:

```
<fact>
    <id>84f4ab12-64e5-4905-9a4f-8935addf7b31</id>
    <decisionDate>2021-12-01</decisionDate>
    <receiver>
        <surname>Kim</surname>
        <firstname>Alla</firstname>
        <addressInfo>
            <type>
                <code>03</code>
                <title>Actual residence</title>
            </type>
            <country>
                <code>033</code>
                <title>Actual residence country</title>
            </country>
            <postIndex>333333</postIndex>
            <region>Region3</region>
        </addressInfo>
        <addressInfo>
            <type>
                <code>01</code>
                <title>Permanent residence</title>
            </type>
            <country>
                <code>011</code>
                <title>Permanent residence country</title>
            </country>
            <postIndex>111111</postIndex>
            <region>Region1</region>
        </addressInfo>  
        <addressInfo>
            <type>
                <code>02</code>
                <title>Temporary residence</title>
            </type>
            <country>
                <code>022</code>
                <title>Temporary residence country</title>
            </country>
            <postIndex>222222</postIndex>
            <region>Region2</region>
        </addressInfo>  
    </receiver>
</fact>
```

Requirements:

1. convert each address block into a block with a name corresponding to the address type
2. wrap the converted address blocks into one "Address"
3. ensure that the blocks follow in a certain order in accordance with the xsd (PermanentResidence -> TemporaryResidence -> ActualResidence)

It was possible to achieve separate conversion of address blocks and wrapping into a common tag (based on xsl:key):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="addressFollowing" match="addressInfo[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::addressInfo]]"
            use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::addressInfo
         [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::addressInfo])][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="addressInfo[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::addressInfo])]">
        <xsl:element name="Address">
            <xsl:call-template name="address"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="key('addressFollowing', generate-id())">
                <xsl:sort select="type/code" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="addressInfo[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::addressInfo]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="addressInfo" mode="copy" name="address">
        <xsl:variable name="addressType">
            <xsl:if test="(.//type//code)=01">
                <xsl:value-of select="'PermanentResidence'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(.//type//code)=02">
                <xsl:value-of select="'TemporaryResidence'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(.//type//code)=03">
                <xsl:value-of select="'ActualResidence'"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$addressType}">
            <xsl:element name="country">
                <xsl:value-of select=".//country//code"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="postIndex">
                <xsl:value-of select=".//postIndex"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="region">
                <xsl:value-of select=".//region"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and sorting of address blocks in the source document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="type/code" />                
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The combined transformation ignores the sorting of the address blocks.

Please help to achieve the combined result in one xsl.
I tried to implement double transformation based on variables and modes, but nothing.
Main idea: sorting the document in first transform, then transform based on key.

Sorry for my English

**UPDATE:**
Desired result:

```
<fact>
   <id>84f4ab12-64e5-4905-9a4f-8935addf7b31</id>
   <decisionDate>2021-12-01</decisionDate>
   <receiver>
      <surname>Kim</surname>
      <firstname>Alla</firstname>
      <Address>
         <PermanentResidence>
            <country>011</country>
            <postIndex>111111</postIndex>
            <region>Region1</region>
         </PermanentResidence>
         <TemporaryResidence>
            <country>022</country>
            <postIndex>222222</postIndex>
            <region>Region2</region>
         </TemporaryResidence>
         <ActualResidence>
            <country>033</country>
            <postIndex>333333</postIndex>
            <region>Region3</region>
         </ActualResidence>      
      </Address>
   </receiver>
</fact>
```

Comment: Are you using an XSLT 2 processor? Can you add the expect result to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2, I think you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="receiver">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::addressInfo)">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
              <Address>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:sort select="type/code"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
              </Address>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="addressInfo">
        <xsl:variable name="addressType">
            <xsl:if test="(.//type//code)=01">
                <xsl:value-of select="'PermanentResidence'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(.//type//code)=02">
                <xsl:value-of select="'TemporaryResidence'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(.//type//code)=03">
                <xsl:value-of select="'ActualResidence'"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$addressType}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="country/code, postIndex, region"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```